# Recursion function not defined error

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, defined

Hi i have a problem with recursion.

i followed this example from wc3 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
But mine seems to not work at all.

```
function rotateImages(start)
  {
  var a = new Array("image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg", "image4.jpg");
  var c = new Array("url1", "url2", "url3", "url4");
  var b = document.getElementById('rotating1');
  var d = document.getElementById('imageurl');
  if(start>=a.length)
      start=0;
  b.src = a[start];
  d.href = c[start];
  window.setTimeout("rotateImages(" + (start+1) + ")",3000);
  }

  rotateImages(0);
```

Firebug throws the error :

```
rotateImages is not defined
[Break On This Error] window.setTimeout('rotateImages('+(start+1)+')',3000);
```

However if i change the timeOut to :

```
window.setTimeout(rotateImages(start+1),3000);
```

It recursives but somehow the delay doesn't work and gives me too much recursion(7000 in a sec)

Comment: W3Schools **is not** the W3C. They are a low quality, advert covered, third party tutorial site with good SEO.

Comment: Any good sites you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be wary of code from W3Schools.

The other answers give a solution. I'll just add that you're recreating the Arrays and repeating the DOM selection every time the `rotateImages` function is called. This is unnecessary.

You can change your code like this:

```
(function() {
    var a = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg", "image4.jpg"];
    var c = ["url1", "url2", "url3", "url4"];
    var b = document.getElementById('rotating1');
    var d = document.getElementById('imageurl');

    function rotateImages(start) {
      b.src = a[start];
      d.href = c[start];
      window.setTimeout(function() {
          rotateImages( ++start % a.length );
      }, 3000);
    }

    rotateImages(0);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers and helping to refactor my code as well!

Comment: i love this line! ++start % a.length

Comment: @Yz Low: You're welcome. Yes, using the modulus operator is a nice way to reset to 0.

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons why `eval` should be avoided, that it breaks scope is one of them. Passing a string to setTimeout causes it to be `eval`ed when the timer runs out.

You should pass a function instead.

```
window.setTimeout(rotateImages(start+1),3000);
```

This calls `rotateImages` immediately, then passes its return value to `setTimeout`. This doesn't help since `rotateImages` doesn't return a function.

You probably want:

```
window.setTimeout(rotateImages,3000,[start+1]);
```

Or create an anonymous function that wraps a closure around start and pass that instead:

```
window.setTimeout(function () { rotateImages(start + 1); },3000);
```

The latter option has better support among browsers.

Comment: The 2nd method doesn't work with internet explorer so the last is preferred (or use a defined function). http://blog.skinkers.com/2011/05/31/fixing-internet-explorers-settimeout-setinterval-scoping-issues-and-overcome-apisframeworks-that-dont-allow-arguments-to-be-passed-to-callback-methods/ has a nice writeup of how to deal with it as well (using a function that returns a function)

Comment: All you need to know about eval is that you shouldn't use it. It screws up scope. It is slow. It is hard to debug. It risks introducing security problems. Use the last example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    rotateImages(start+1);
},3000);
```

`setTimeout()` expects a function reference as the 1st parameter. Simply putting a function call there would give the return value of te function as the parameter, this is why the delay did not work. However your first try with evaluating a string was a good approach, but it is not recommended.

Comment: Now i understand.. How do i know when I should put the function call?

Comment: If you need your function's return value. If you want to give your function (to call it later) you should use the function reference (without the braces) or an anonymous function.